# how to rewrite the programme?

Tags: java, arrays

the program is too long.

In the upper part Is it the way to use a loop.

I try it use for loop `i` for column and looping 2-9 to make it shorter.

Having a problem nesting for loops.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class cardGameArray {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String[][] card = new String[4][13];
        
        //Spades
        card [0][0] = "SA";
        card [0][1] = "S2";
        card [0][2] = "S3";
        card [0][3] = "S4";
        card [0][4] = "S5";
        card [0][5] = "S6";
        card [0][6] = "S7";
        card [0][7] = "S8";
        card [0][8] = "S9";
        card [0][9] = "ST";
        card [0][10] = "SJ";
        card [0][11] = "SQ";
        card [0][12] = "SK";
        
        //Hearts
        card [1][0] = "HA";
        card [1][1] = "H2";
        card [1][2] = "H3";
        card [1][3] = "H4";
        card [1][4] = "H5";
        card [1][5] = "H6";
        card [1][6] = "H7";
        card [1][7] = "H8";
        card [1][8] = "H9";
        card [1][9] = "HT";
        card [1][10] = "HJ";
        card [1][11] = "HQ";
        card [1][12] = "HK";
        
        //Diamonds
        card [2][0] = "DA";
        card [2][1] = "D2";
        card [2][2] = "D3";
        card [2][3] = "D4";
        card [2][4] = "D5";
        card [2][5] = "D6";
        card [2][6] = "D7";
        card [2][7] = "D8";
        card [2][8] = "D9";
        card [2][9] = "DT";
        card [2][10] = "DJ";
        card [2][11] = "DQ";
        card [2][12] = "DK";
        
        //Clubs
        card [3][0] = "CA";
        card [3][1] = "C2";
        card [3][2] = "C3";
        card [3][3] = "C4";
        card [3][4] = "C5";
        card [3][5] = "C6";
        card [3][6] = "C7";
        card [3][7] = "C8";
        card [3][8] = "C9";
        card [3][9] = "CT";
        card [3][10] = "CJ";
        card [3][11] = "CQ";
        card [3][12] = "CK";
        System.out.print("Spades"+"\n");
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
            System.out.print(card[0][i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Hearts"+"\n");
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
            System.out.print(card[1][i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Diamonds"+"\n");
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
            System.out.print(card[2][i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Clubs"+"\n");
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
            System.out.print(card[3][i]+"\t");
        }   
    }
}
```

It out is:

```
Spades
SA      S2      S3      S4      S5      S6      S7      S8      S9      ST      SJ      SQ      SK
Hearts
HA      H2      H3      H4      H5      H6      H7      H8      H9      HT      HJ      HQ      HK
Diamonds
DA      D2      D3      D4      D5      D6      D7      D8      D9      DT      DJ      DQ      DK
Clubs
CA      C2      C3      C4      C5      C6      C7      C8      C9      CT      CJ      CQ      CK
```

I try this way:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    int ans;
    public class cardGameArray {
        public static void main( String[] args ){
            String[][] card = new String[4][13];
            card[0][0] = SA;
            //Spades
            ans = short(card);
public static int short(int[] card ) {
            for(int i = 1; i<9 i++){
                 for(int k = 2; i<9; k++){
                     card[0][i] = "S" + k;
                 }
            }
            return ans;
         }
    }
```

It becomes this way after fishing the `k` 2 - 9 then loop `i` it has 81.

So output only display S9; instead of S2 - S9.

```
SA
S9
S9
S9
S9
S9
S9
S9
S9
S9
```

the logic error of this.

Comment: If you want help nesting for loops, show us what you tried.

Comment: Questions about refactoring working code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can try Code Review. Check their rules before posting

Comment: This is too broad of a question. Your program can be improved in many ways, all resulting in a "smaller" program.

Comment: The second `for` loop is obviously wrong (`i` instead of `k`) but I don't understand why you don't end in infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take this approach:

```
public class CardsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] suit = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
        String[] values = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

        String[][] cards = new String[4][13];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                cards[i][j] = values[j] + " of " + suit[i];
            }
        }
        
        Stream.of(cards).flatMap(Stream::of).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The output of this program will is

```
Ace of Hearts
2 of Hearts
3 of Hearts
4 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
6 of Hearts
7 of Hearts
8 of Hearts
...
```